# Time derivative with reference frame gives error

Tags: python, sympy

Say I want to calculate the symbolic expression of the following

```
$$
\frac{d(x(t)\hat{i} + 2x(t)\hat{j})}{dt}
$$
```

```
from sympy import diff, Symbol
from sympy.physics.vector import dynamicsymbols, ReferenceFrame
x = dynamicsymbols('x')
N = ReferenceFrame('N')
f = x*N.x + 2*x*N.y
diff(f, Symbol('t'))
```

This returns with a cryptic error

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'x'
```

What am I doing wrong here?  I can't imagine sympy not being able to handle differentiation with reference frames.

PS: Why do I seem to not be able to use MathJax in stackoverflow?

Answer (score 0):

There is another [`diff`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/physics/vector/api/classes.html?highlight=diff#sympy.physics.vector.vector.Vector.diff) for `sympy.physics` which lets you also specify the reference frame for the derivative.  The correct way to call `diff` on `f` is

```
f.diff(Symbol('t'), N)
```